# Solve heat equation $γv'' + λv = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, heat-equation

I need some help with the following questions:

If $γ>0$ and $λ ≤ 0$.

1) I have to find all solutions to the diﬀerential equation

$γv'' + λv = 0$.

2) Then, I have to prove that the only solution that satisﬁes the boundary conditions $v(0) = 0$, $v(l)=0$ , is the zero solution $v(x) ≡ 0$.

I tried to find the answer to the first question and I eventually found:

$v = A + Be^{-λt/γ}$.

I am for sure that this is NOT right. But, I cannot find any other solution. So any help would be grateful

Comment: As a hint for one way of doing this: the equation is second order and linear, so you can find its characteristic equation: $\gamma r^2 + \lambda = 0$ and solve algebraically for $r$.  This tells you your solutions by substituting $r$ in for the ansatz $v=e^{rt}$.

Comment: Your equation can be rewritten as $v'' + \alpha v = 0$, where $\alpha = \lambda / \gamma$, since $\gamma > 0$. Usually, you solve this looking for roots of the algebraic equation $m^2 + \alpha = 0$ (why?). If you are looking for real functions as solutions, your expression will depend on whether you have real roots or complex roots.

Hint for 2): if you know existence and uniqueness results for the ODE, you don't need 1) to prove 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the equation as 
$$v′′+\alpha v=0$$
where $\alpha = \frac{\lambda}{\gamma}\leq 0$ is well defined as $\gamma > 0$. Then analyze the characteristic equation
$$r^2+\alpha=0$$
which as $\alpha \le 0$ gives two roots
$$r_1=\sqrt{\alpha},~~r_2=-\sqrt{\alpha}$$
so the general solution is
$$v(t)=c_1e^{\sqrt{\alpha}t}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{\alpha}t}\tag{1}$$
which after substituting $\alpha = \frac{\lambda}{\gamma}$ forms
$$v(t)=c_1e^{\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{\gamma}}t}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{\gamma}}t}\tag{2}$$
then evaluate the boundary conditions using $(1)$
$$ v(0)=0 \implies c_1+c_2=0 $$
$$ v(l)=0 \implies c_1e^{\sqrt{\alpha}l}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{\alpha}l}=0$$
so that 
$$c_1+c_2=0 \implies c_2=-c_1$$
and
$$c_1e^{\sqrt{\alpha}l}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{\alpha}l}=0 \implies c_1e^{\sqrt{\alpha}l}= c_1e^{-\sqrt{\alpha}l} \iff c_1 = 0$$
then by our first condition
$$c_2=0$$
therefore
$$v(t)\equiv 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Assume the solution takes the general form

$$v(t) = Ae^{at}+Be^{-at}$$

Plug into $γv'' + λv = 0$ to get

$$a^2 γ + λ =0$$

Solve for the exponential coefficient $a$

$$a=\sqrt{ \frac{|λ|}{γ}}$$

Then, with the boundary conditions,

$$v(0)=A+B=0$$
$$v(l)=Ae^{al}+Be^{-al}=0$$

Solve for $A$ and $B$,

$$A=B=0$$

Thus, $v(t) = 0$.